# how to set permission to device /dev/rfcomm0?

Tags: bluetooth, kannel

I am trying to run kannel bearer box but i got error something like could not write/read device. I think kannel doest have permission to read/write bluetooth device /dev/rfcomm0

Thanks for reading. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

with root account do

```
chmod a+rw /dev/rfcomm0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which program is generating the error message, run the program with `strace` and see which system call yields the error. If it's `open`, then the `chmod` solution recommended by Francis should do the trick. If it's `read` or `write`, then you should investigate further: is there a problem in the kernel or the appication code.

Answer (score 0):

Permission to access the bluetooth device can be added by checking the device file group using ls -h and adding current user to that group with following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G <rfcomm0 group> $USER
```